# Verify first and last name in textbox

Tags: vb.net

In my program, the user must fill in he's first and last name in a textbox. When he don't enters he's whole name, a messagebox must appear with: "Fill in your whole name."
I know it's something with:

```
Dim words As String() = textbox1.text.Split(" ")
```

Can someone help me please?

Comment: You should have separate textboxes for first and surnames or else you will forever be splitting the values up

Comment: But it should be possible in 1 textbox, right?

Comment: Do you have a dictionary of valid names? Do you want to exclude numbers as valid names. What about people that only have one name?

Comment: Collecting and storing the data with the user's explicit intent will make your life much easier going forward. You can always format/merge them for displaying them to the user afterwards.

Comment: It is possible. Do you really want to handle every possible case? For example, your current code doesn't handle two spaces correctly. What if someone uses last, First or Last, First Middle Initial or First Middle Last?

Comment: People may have more than 2 names (first and last). How about parsing `Michael Sylvester Gardenzio Stallone`? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middle_name

Comment: `Mr. Michael Sylvester Gardenzio Stallone Jr`... your prompt is after all, asking for the "whole name"

Comment: how about C-3PO, Cher, Crapbag? http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: or even 王秀英, 田中太郎, H'timS or  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Prince_logo.svg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use [`String.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), something like this,

```
Dim valid = textBox1.Text.Split( _
        " ", _
        StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Length > 1
```

but, **your question shows you haven't really thought this through**. Checking that you have a space surrounded by non-space characters doesn't really validate the text as a name.